# Editor for ConTeXt

Tags: context, editors, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ConTeXt editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/context-editors)

I am searching for a "good" ConTeXt Editor (with engine LuaTeX) for Win7. With LaTeX and pdfTeX I used TeXstudio, but there is no syntax highlightning for ConTeXt (if I am not wrong). And TeXworks is perfect enough for me, but it does not support code folding, which is important for me. So I am searching for an editor with ConTeXt-Highlightning, an integrated strong pdf-viewer, and code-folding, any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see there, if all three properties are fulfilled, hopefully someone can answer this, so I don't have to try them out.

Comment: Emacs+AucTeX (as [mentioned here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Text_Editors) and linked from the duplicate) is a combination capable of what you're looking for; though configuring it might be non-trivial.

Comment: The [ConTeXt editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/context-editors) question (and answers) could be extended to deal with such feature requests too.

Comment: I am not able to add my question as a comment in that "ConTeXt editors" question, how to do that?